# how to convert my HTML into SafeHtml in GWT

Tags: html, gwt

how can I change my Html into SafeHtml

```
Html htmlText = new Html();
htmlText.setText(result.getText());
```

I am saving a resume in my htmlText, but I want to save it as SafeHtml

how can I convert the above html into safehtml ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlUtils`, this class provides utility methods for creating SafeHtml, the simplest way to solve your problem is to use

```
SafeHtml safeHtml = SafeHtmlUtils.fromString(result.getText());
```

Comment: thanks, I applied your code, in safeHtml my result is coming , but its not appeaing in my browser  , i am adding in my widget like this resumeScrollPanel.add((HTML) htmlResumeText);   . am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That is the point of SafeHtml, to prevent html from being added to the page in a way that cause content to be drawn that you didn't intend. If you want to turn a string that you absolutly trust into a SafeHtml object, use the SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString instead.

Comment: i did it, but still nothing appearing, any idea

Comment: Once you have the SafeHtml object you can use it in the same way as you used the html string previously using the asString method. The html returned by asString will be safe to use, try:  resumeScrollPanel.add((HTML)safeHtmlResumeText.asString()); Another way to use safe html is to use the constructor of HTML which takes a SafeHtml object.